# sapui5 Gateway timeout Timer

Tags: timeout, sapui5

I would like your help on this matter, because googling didnt return any valid results.

So we have a requirement to display an active session countdown timer in the app, so user can see after how long time the session from Gateway will end.

What is the best way to achieve this?

I realize I can request timer before next call if user has been idle, but is there away to warn user beforehand in SAPUI5? Using Cloud-Gateway-Backend?

Comment: cloud as in, cloud platform? with a destination?

Comment: yes. SCP with destination to Gateway and RFC to backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently as stated by SAP representative in OSS Incident we opened on this issue - there is no such API or method on Gateway, but as this is is extremely important for user friendliness and also security - it was raised as initiative.
As a workaround used custom coded timers, called after every gateway call.